# Ajax redirect in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and I am facing an issue in Ajax redirect. In normal post or get call we can return the user to some specific page like:

```
return RedirectToAction("AllStudents");
```

but using json, it's different or may be I don't know much about it.

I have posted my code in normal and also converted to Ajax.

**What I have tried**

Controller code in general:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    stude.DeleteStudent(id);
    return RedirectToAction("AllStudents");
}
```

and I have use Ajax which do the work successfully but it is not redirecting the user to another page, like in the above code it redirects the users to another page.

My Ajax controller code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Delete(int id)
    {
        stude.DeleteStudent(id);
        return Json("true",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My Js code:

```
  // Delete record
        $("#del").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $("#stid").val();
           //alert(id);
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "Delete/" + id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                  data: JSON.stringify(id),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);

                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log('Failed to get data' + err);
                }
            });


        });
```

The action is performed and data is deleted but the browser stop like:

[updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkgEV.jpg)

**My goal:** I want that the data is deleted without the page refresh, like it normally does. Also please share a link, post, something which shows the page refresh using ajax. like I want to refresh a page after every 1 minute but without reloading it.

**Update:** The data is now deleting but the **Red** highlighted (page) is not refreshing, I have to manually refresh, which I don't want. I want to refresh it silently without reload it.

Answer (score 0):

if you will refresh the grid only then create a timeout method are follow as:

```
 setTimeout(function() {get grid data by ajax call}, 10000);
```

if you want to reload the whole page then

1. create one partial view.
2. create an action method and return PartialView().
3. create ajax call and getting response to add in div like divid.html(data);

if you refresh the page every 1 min then create a time out function and create a simple ajax.

```
 setTimeout(function() { ajax call}, 10000);
```